# Android listView wrong child position when slide right

Tags: java, android

I am facing an issue when trying to update my `ListView` after scrolling it down:

```
public void onSwipeRight(ListView listView, int [] reverseSortedPositions) {
    LoadFromDB task = new LoadFromDB();
    String term;
    View v;
    int childIndex = reverseSortedPositions[0];
    v = listView.getChildAt(reverseSortedPositions[0]);
    tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_ddItem);
}
```

Before I do the scroll on screen, I can get the right position and the right textView from the right child (row). After scrolling down I get an `NullPointerException`.

P.S `reverseSortedPositions[0]` is always returning the correct position in the array.

Answer (score 1):

A ListView does not have as many child views as your array - It recycles views. 
If you see 5 items on screen the list will have around 10 views total, and they will be reused as you scroll. Basically as soon as you start scrolling you lose the relation between the index of array and the ListView's child view index.

Chet hasse has a great piece about swipe-to-delete and deletetion animation on ListViews. I suggest you start there, it's pretty much exactly what you need (He also provides working code examples to download).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCHNAi9kJI4